# mongodrop slow on small db

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I'm using a real Mongo instance for my integration tests.
On every test, I call `mongorestore my_db_state --drop` because I need a clean db to start the next test.

On my tiny db (with only one test user account) it takes `180 ms` to run `mongorestore my_db_state` (without `--drop`) and `455 ms` with `--drop`.

I don't understand why it's taking so long to drop the db, but how can I speed this up?

I may have a bunch of different connections on the mongo server because I never close them on my Flask server, but they probably should be closed after the test is over...just not sure if this is an issue to care about.

Is there a faster way to restore a snapshot to its original state for testing purposes?

Comment: when you run `--drop` it is not only removing the database, but also the indexes. So there are 2 extra steps, and I presume there is nothing you can to do avoid it. What you can try is not to use `--drop`. What happens here? it will only insert new documents, and error out those already existing without any update

Comment: try `--noIndexRestore`

Answer (score 0):

Drop and recreate collections from your test runner using persistent MongoClient instances.

Comment: mongoclient instances?

Comment: What do you mean by this?